# How do I boost a result based on a static value in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I boost results based on their document type?

We're using ElasticSearch to power the search feature on a website. My client has asked if their Products and Services pages can bubble up to the top of the results, but not in a totally artificial way.

For example, say the results as they stand right now were:

| Result | Score |
| --- | --- |
| News Article 1 | 99 |
| News Article 2 | 80 |
| News Article 3 | 70 |
| Service 1 | 60 |
| News Article 4 | 50 |
| Product 2 | 40 |
| News Article 5 | 30 |

Maybe we give Products and Services a 25 point boost so the results would come out in a semi-organic manner, like so.

| Result | Score |
| --- | --- |
| News Article 1 | 99 |
| Service 1 | 85 |
| News Article 2 | 80 |
| News Article 3 | 70 |
| Product 2 | 65 |
| News Article 4 | 50 |
| News Article 5 | 30 |

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a combination of [`bool/should`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) clause along with boost applied on the [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html#term-field-params)

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "name": {
              "value": "Product 2",
              "boost": 25
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "name": {
              "value": "Service 1",
              "boost": 25
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```